# How to print xml soap api result as json or xml with php

Tags: php, xml, api, soap

**How to print xml soap api result as json or xml with php **
I have not worked with SOAP API before. I want to execute a SOAP API with XML data request. I have tried but did not get result.

```
  // The URL to POST to
  $url = "https://api.tbotechnology.in/HotelAPI_V7/HotelService.svc";
  // The value for the SOAPAction: header
  $action = "http://TekTravel/HotelBookingApi/CountryList";

  // Get the SOAP data into a string, I am using HEREDOC syntax
  // but how you do this is irrelevant, the point is just get the
  // body of the request into a string
  $mySOAP = <<<EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<soap:Envelope 
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:hot="http://TekTravel/HotelBookingApi">
  <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <hot:Credentials UserName="***" Password="***"> </hot:Credentials> 
    <wsa:Action>http://TekTravel/HotelBookingApi/CountryList</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:To>https://api.tbotechnology.in/HotelAPI_V7/HotelService.svc</wsa:To>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <hot:CountryListRequest/>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
EOD;

$headers = array(
'Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8',
'Content-Length: '.strlen($mySOAP),
'SOAPAction: ' .$action
);

// Build the cURL session
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $mySOAP);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

// Send the request and check the response
if (($result = curl_exec($ch)) === FALSE) {
die('cURL error: '.curl_error($ch)."<br />\n");
} else {
echo "Success!<br />\n";
echo $result;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: i changed header to this code 

`$headers = array(
'Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8',
'Accept: text/xml',
'Cache-Control: no-cache',
'Pragma: no-cache',
'Content-Length: '.strlen($mySOAP),
'SOAPAction: ' .$action
);
`


but also not work

Comment: There's an [edit] link right under the question. Please use it to add codes to question. __Do not__ paste codes in comments, it becomes __unreadable__.

Comment: It appears you've just pasted your API credentials to a public site -- you'll want to change your password immediately.

Comment: Use an SOAP library - not the XML directly. For SOAP, XML is the INTERNAL serialization format. It makes debugging and implementing a SOAP library a lot easier - but in the most cases you should not access it directly. The SOAP library will give you specific objects, implement JSON serialization for them.